# How to create a recursive loop that takes user feedback in excel

Tags: excel, text, vba

I need to create a .dat file generator which has the following format

```
Fhead 010101 (some data here)
Thead 01010 (similarly here)
Tcustomer -do-
TItem -do-
TTail -do-
Thead 01010 (similarly here)
Tcustomer -do-
TItem -do-
TTail -do-
Ftail -do-
```

As you can see the data is repeated here but will be different in content depending on the user.

I tried concatenating using the concatenate formula and was able to get a .dat file, but the problem now is how do I make it ask the user how many theads there will be and accordingly make the rest of the file?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Tanmay

Comment: what makes you need to use recursion?

Comment: I agree with @PJRosenburg, a simple loop should suffice. But not enough information is given to give a clear answer. Better if you show us a snippet of your code where you build the file and what you have tried for user input.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an input box, then assign a variable the result and use it throughout your code.  Is this what you are asking?

```
Dim TuserIn As String
Dim TuserInNum As Long

TuserIn = InputBox("Input Thead")    'Gets the user input as a string
TuserInNum = CLng(TuserIn)             'Converts to a Long variable type
```